# how do I get the correct latest release branch name using shell sort?

Tags: git, shell, sorting

In our project we periodically checkout new branches called `release/2.4` or the like. Currently if I `git branch -r | grep -o "release/[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*$"` it would generate the output as follows:

```
release/2.29
release/2.30
release/2.31
release/2.32
release/2.4
release/2.5
release/2.6
release/2.7
release/2.8
release/2.9
release/3.0
release/3.1
release/3.10
release/3.11
release/3.2
release/3.3
release/3.4
release/3.5
release/3.6
release/3.7
release/3.8
release/3.9
```

As you can see, the latest release branch is certainly `release/3.11`, however it is positioned between `release/3.1` and `release/3.2`.

I have tried `git branch -r | grep -o "release/[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*$" | sort -n -t "." -k 2 | tail -1` to first separate the sequence by "." and sort by the second column. However, this yields `release/2.32` since 32 is much larger.

How do I use shell script (probably command `sort` or `sed`) to get `release/3.11`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sort --version-sort` or `sort -V`.

Comment: @Andreas: have you tried it? `git branch -r | grep ... | sort -V` lists the versions in an appropriately sorted order.

Comment: @torek thanks as always. And @Andreas thanks for your comments. I gave the answer because OP asks about `shell sort`. `sort --version-sort` and `sort -V` are complete commands. `--version-sort` itself explains very well why it works. *What's the first letter of you name, Andreas? Yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*